# How to Fix Permission Denied in Docker Vieux/sshfs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I'am using vieux/sshfs as docker plugin. And I try to mount my data on another server. When creating it in docker-compose it gives me permission denied? Any Idea?

```
version: "3.4" 
  services: 
        app:
         image: ubuntu:latest
         volumes: 
            - sshvolume:/app
   volumes:
        sshvolume:
          driver: vieux/sshfs
          driver_opts:
             sshcmd: "user@ip:/path/to/host"
             password: "pass"
             allow_other: ""
```

And I use to run it by:

`docker-compose up`

PS: I edit my question. After restarting the Docker Daemon the permission denied disappear. I don't know what happened. Weird

Comment: Please provide more details about your setup like the the docker-compose file and the command you are using to start up containers.

Comment: You can edit your question and use syntax highlighting for code. That makes it easier to read.

Comment: Hi I edit my question @adebasi

Comment: Thanks for editing. And good to hear that it works now